# Why are my drop down lists selecting the same value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a set of asp.net drop down lists that give users the option to select names for a production crew. The names are used to show production crews associated with rows in a Production table. These lists all have the same set of names (the names are selected from, and the entries are stored to a SQL server database). To accomplish this, I added the names to my first list with a SQL call and added the names to other lists using the AddRange method like below (all in the C# code behind):

```
PopulateList(ddlTM1); // calls the method in which a SQL call is used to populate the list
ddlTM2.Items.AddRange(ddlTM1.Items.OfType<ListItem>().ToArray());
ddlTM3.Items.AddRange(ddlTM1.Items.OfType<ListItem>().ToArray());
```

This is working as expected. However, I am making the lists select any names that were already selected in previous submissions. Here is the setup for that:

```
String strCommand = "SELECT * FROM tblCrew, tblPerson WHERE tblCrew.PersonID = tblPerson.Id " +
                    "AND tblCrew.ProductionID = " + Session["ProductionID"].ToString();
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strCommand, connection);
SqlDataReader reader;
try
{
    reader.Read();
    ddlCrew1.SelectedIndex = ddlCrew1.Items.IndexOf(ddl.Items.FindByValue(reader["Id"].ToString()));
    reader.Close();
}
catch (Exception err){}
connection.Close();
```

The problem is, this selects the given value for every drop down list. Even setting the selected index for subsequent lists changes all lists to the same selected value (basically, the last selected name will be shown in all lists; on the bright side, the name is always correct). I am confused as to why this is happening, and how I can counteract this. The lists can still be selected independent of each other by the user, and all names are saved properly. However, I would like to show what names already exist for an existing entry.

Comment: Try clearing the selection: `ddlTM2.ClearSelection();`

Comment: It could be because of shallow copy while adding items to `ddlTM2` and `ddlTM3`